# Stop brightness dimming on laptop, Samsung nc10

Tags: laptop

I have a Samsung nc10 and whenever I am not plugged in and there is a small period of inactivity my brightness dims.

I can't find any way to return to normal when using again except restarting.

There are function keys for this but they seem to disable when it does the dim.

I have looked at power and battery settings and can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Samsung provides their [own software](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/download/supportDown.do?group=itbusiness&type=notebookcomputers&subtype=nseries&model_nm=NP-NC10&disp_nm=NC10&language=&cate_type=all&dType=D&mType=SW&vType=&prd_ia_cd=&model_cd=&menu=download), like "Easy Display Manager" or "Battery Life Extender".

Maybe you have one of them installed, which has such option (I would bet on the "Battery Life Extender").

---

**Edit** : Checking the [manual](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/download/supportDownDetail.do?group=itbusiness&type=notebookcomputers&subtype=nseries&model_nm=NP-NC10&disp_nm=NC10&language=&cate_type=all&mType=UM&dType=D&vType=&cttID=2151313&prd_ia_cd=&model_cd=&menu=download&menu2=detail), it seems you have the "LCD Auto-Dimming" option in "Samsung Battery Manager" (Start > All Programs > Samsung > Samsung Battery Manager > Samsung Battery Manager)

[image: Samsung Battery Manager]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the settings of the Power Management on your computer by going into the Control Panel in Windows. From there you can adjust the settings so that the computer will not treat battery operation any different than if it were plugged in (this will obviously lead to more battery drain).

Comment: He said he already checked power and battery settings, so I'm guessing there is a proprietary software taking over it.

Comment: Gnoupi: Or the hardware itself does its thing without caring to notify the OS.

Comment: @Johannes : True, that happens too... I have this for the frequency of my graphical card, really annoying (can't have full performance when on a trip)